# MVC: Get List of values from Database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pull data from my database in my MVC Controller. This is the code I have but not sure if I'm doing this right using a LINQ query

```
public class EditProfileController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var listdata = db.Users.ToList().Select(x => new FE.Models.AspNetUsers
        {
            Id = x.Id,
           // (repeat the same for all)
        }).ToList();
    }
}
```

Get error on Index:

> EditProfileController.Index(): not all code paths return a value FE

and on db:

> The name db does not exist in the current context

How can I pull data from a database table to create a list view? Should I use LINQ and if so what am I missing from my code above?

Comment: Where are you injecting/declaring db? Also, you don't return anything. You need to return listData.

Comment: How do I declare db?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything you should return your list:

```
public class EditProfileController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var listdata = db.Users.ToList().Select(x => new FE.Models.AspNetUsers
        {
            Id = x.Id,
           // (repeat the same for all)
        }).ToList();
        return Ok(listdata);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes adding the return helps. How do I fix the db.Users.ToList. I still get an error 'The name db does not exist in the current context' on that.

Comment: @bootsy Create object of your DB Context Class with name of "db" in your class or in function as your requirement  to access the database Tables

Comment: I added private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext(); but I get an error on on new ApplicationDbContext 'There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'options' of 'ApplicationDbContext.ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext>)'

Answer (score 0):

I only work with VB (use C# converter) so here is how I get get a list of values from my DB:

```
Public Function Index()
   dim listData as List(Of Users) = new List(Of Users)

  Using db as new YourDB()
    listData = db.Users.Select(Function(x) x.Id = id).ToList()
  End Using

  return listdata
End Function
```

Or you can just use an `IQueryable` of your model.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class EditProfileController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<FE.Models.AspNetUsers> listdata = new List<FE.Models.AspNetUsers>();
        using(ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            listdata = db.Users.Select(x => new FE.Models.AspNetUsers
            {
                Id = x.Id,
               // (repeat the same for all)
            }).ToList();
        }

        return View(listdata)
    }
}
```

I made a couple assumptions that you are trying to pass the list to a view rather than returning the list of `AspNetUsers` and your db context is working. Make sure in your view you declare the model like so:

```
@model IEnumerable<FE.Models.AspNetUsers>
```